# Noun for someone who is looking for kicks, thrills or excitement

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is there a single (non-colloquial) noun/word which describes a person who seeks/is looking for thrills, excitement or 'kicks'?

For context, I am an English mother tongue translator (Italian to English) and I am currently considering using the word 'adventurer'. The surrounding sentence goes like this (after translation):

> The Festival provides a dynamic platform for contemporary photographers, visual storytellers, knowledge seekers and **adventurers**.

The LITERAL translation from Italian would be ('cercatore di emozioni'): seekers of excitement (thrills) but I prefer 'adventurer' as a one-word option that encompasses the overall meaning of the Italian phrase in this specific context. If anyone can think of a better word I'd love to hear it!

Comment: How do you imagine using the word in a sentence? Context can be very important in deciding on such a word.

Comment: Hi and thanks for visiting EL&U. To get the most out of your time here there are a couple of things you should do. First is to take the [tour] and second is to get into the habit of reading the tag info when you use tags. The single-word-requests tag has a [whole page of information](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info), including a checklist, to help you write a good question and include all the required details. if you take a look there are revise your question it is less likely to get downvoted or closed.  Cheers

Comment: The (event) provides a dynamic platform for contemporary photographers, visual storytellers, knowledge seekers and adventurers.

Answer (score 5):

How about **thrill-seeker**, defined on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thrill-seeker) as:

> thrill-seeker *(n)* A person who enjoys thrilling situations, or who engages in dangerous sports

Comment: Thanks Peter.  I am an English mother tongue translator (Italian to English) and I have chosen the word 'adventurer'. The context is this (after translation): The Festival provides a dynamic platform for contemporary photographers, visual storytellers, knowledge seekers and adventurers. The LITERAL translation from Italian would be ('cercatore di emozioni'): seekers of excitement (thrills) but I prefer 'adventurer' as a one-word option that encompasses the overall meaning of the Italian phrase in this specific context. If anyone can think of a better word I'd love to hear it ! Thanks again.

Comment: @Rubolo The word "adventurer" is something more generalized that doesn't have the same specific meaning as something as who is "looking for thrills, excitement, or 'kicks'." (Somebody who gambles for excitement would not be called an *adventurer*.) If you prefer *adventurer* to *thrill-seeker*, you should edit your question to make your criteria clearer.